# A matrix manipulation from Berezin's paper

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I am reading a paper by Berezin, entitled *General Concept of Quantization*. He writes:

[image]

and then:

[image]

This ought to be some clever manipulation of matrices and yet I am not able to show how (1.4) follows from (1.1) if $\omega$ is given to be invertible.

Any leads?

Comment: It should follow from the fact that $d(\omega^{ij}\omega_{jk})=0$. The main issue is how was (1.1) derived (perhaps footnote 1 explains it)?

Comment: @TedBlack (1.1) is taken as the definition. The footnote is just a comment on how the repeated index notation will stand for sum. Btw, I did try doing that already, and didn't seem to get anywhere... :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we multiply,
$$\omega^{\gamma k}\frac{\partial \omega^{\alpha\beta}}{\partial x^k}
+\omega^{\beta k}\frac{\partial \omega^{\gamma\alpha}}{\partial x^k}
+\omega^{\alpha k}\frac{\partial \omega^{\beta\gamma}}{\partial x^k}=0$$
by $\omega_{i\alpha}\omega_{j\beta}\omega_{l\gamma}$ we get,
$$
\omega_{i\alpha}\omega_{j\beta}\omega_{l\gamma}\omega^{\gamma k}\frac{\partial \omega^{\alpha\beta}}{\partial x^k}
+\omega_{i\alpha}\omega_{j\beta}\omega_{l\gamma}\omega^{\beta k}\frac{\partial \omega^{\gamma\alpha}}{\partial x^k}
+\omega_{i\alpha}\omega_{j\beta}\omega_{l\gamma}\omega^{\alpha k}\frac{\partial \omega^{\beta\gamma}}{\partial x^k}=0
$$
Since $\omega_{l\gamma}\omega^{\gamma k}=\delta^k_l$, $\omega_{j\beta}\omega^{\beta k}=\delta^k_j$, $\omega_{i\alpha}\omega^{\alpha k}=\delta^k_i$ we have,
$$
\omega_{i\alpha}\omega_{j\beta}\delta^k_l\frac{\partial \omega^{\alpha\beta}}{\partial x^k}
+\omega_{i\alpha}\omega_{l\gamma}\delta^k_j\frac{\partial \omega^{\gamma\alpha}}{\partial x^k}
+\omega_{j\beta}\omega_{l\gamma}\delta^k_i\frac{\partial \omega^{\beta\gamma}}{\partial x^k}=0
$$
or,
\begin{equation}
\omega_{i\alpha}\omega_{j\beta}\frac{\partial \omega^{\alpha\beta}}{\partial x^l}
+\omega_{i\alpha}\omega_{l\gamma}\frac{\partial \omega^{\gamma\alpha}}{\partial x^j}
+\omega_{j\beta}\omega_{l\gamma}\frac{\partial \omega^{\beta\gamma}}{\partial x^i}=0 \tag{I} \label{I}
\end{equation}
Since,
$$
\omega_{i\alpha}\omega^{\alpha \beta} = \delta^\beta_i
$$
we have,
$$
\omega_{i\alpha} \frac{\partial \omega^{\alpha \beta}}{\partial x^l}
+
\omega^{\alpha \beta} \frac{\partial \omega_{i\alpha}}{\partial x^l}=0
\Rightarrow
\omega_{i\alpha} \frac{\partial \omega^{\alpha \beta}}{\partial x^l}=-
\omega^{\alpha \beta} \frac{\partial \omega_{i\alpha}}{\partial x^l}
$$
In the same way,
$$
\omega_{l\gamma} \frac{\partial \omega^{\gamma \alpha}}{\partial x^j}=-
\omega^{\gamma\alpha} \frac{\partial \omega_{l\gamma}}{\partial x^j}
$$
and,
$$
\omega_{j\beta} \frac{\partial \omega^{\beta \gamma}}{\partial x^i}=-
\omega^{\beta\gamma} \frac{\partial \omega_{j\beta}}{\partial x^i}
$$
So we can rewrite (\ref{I}) as,
$$
-\omega_{j\beta}\omega^{\alpha\beta}
\frac{\partial \omega_{i\alpha}}{\partial x^l}
-\omega_{i\alpha}\omega^{\gamma\alpha}
\frac{\partial \omega_{l\gamma}}{\partial x^j}
-\omega_{l\gamma}\omega^{\beta\gamma}
\frac{\partial \omega_{j\beta}}{\partial x^i}
=0
$$
Using the skew-symmetric property of $\omega$ we have,
$$
\omega_{j\beta}\omega^{\beta\alpha}
\frac{\partial \omega_{i\alpha}}{\partial x^l}
+\omega_{i\alpha}\omega^{\alpha\gamma}
\frac{\partial \omega_{l\gamma}}{\partial x^j}
+\omega_{l\gamma}\omega^{\gamma\beta}
\frac{\partial \omega_{j\beta}}{\partial x^i}
=0
$$
and since $\omega_{j\beta}\omega^{\beta\alpha}=\delta^\alpha_j$,
$\omega_{i\alpha}\omega^{\alpha\gamma}=\delta^\gamma_i$,
$\omega_{l\gamma}\omega^{\gamma\beta}=\delta^\beta_l$
we have,
$$
\delta^\alpha_j
\frac{\partial \omega_{i\alpha}}{\partial x^l}
+\delta^\gamma_i
\frac{\partial \omega_{l\gamma}}{\partial x^j}
+\delta^\beta_l
\frac{\partial \omega_{j\beta}}{\partial x^i}
=0
$$
or,
$$
\frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial x^l}
+
\frac{\partial \omega_{li}}{\partial x^j}
+
\frac{\partial \omega_{jl}}{\partial x^i}
=0
$$
Replace $l$ with $k$:
$$
\frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial x^k}
+
\frac{\partial \omega_{ki}}{\partial x^j}
+
\frac{\partial \omega_{jk}}{\partial x^i}
=0
$$
to get (1.4).

Comment: That was super! How did you intuit that? Also, can you confirm that anti-symmetry is used in proving both directions?

Comment: Nothing like that, just threw darts until I hit the board. Let me come back to you on the skew-symmetric part.

Comment: Added a few more steps for the reverse direction; the use of the skew-symmetric property is shown.

Comment: There was a mistake in last derivation; somehow I managed to insert the tensor product in the partials. This is not the case; instead we have to use $\omega_{i\alpha}\omega^{\alpha\beta}=\delta^\beta_i$ to derive a relation between the partial of the covariant and contravariant tensors.

Comment: I wish there was a way to upvote it twice!